# Hashmap is put into alphabetical order?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a HashMap defined as follow:

```
private final Map<String, DataTable> reports = new HashMap();
```

When I put new entries into this HashMap they end up in Alphabetical order based on the key. Why is it doing this? How do I put them in the order I added them to the HashMap?

Comment: What do you mean "end up in alphabetical order"? Can you show more of the code?

Comment: HashMaps are not ordered. TreeMaps are.

Comment: String's natural order **is** alphabetical order, and `HashMap` isn't ordered.

Comment: use linkedHashmap if you need insertion order

Comment: Please also note that the trend in the JDK goes to changing the iteration order more frequently, i.e. it may differ at every startup of the JVM. At least they implemented it this way for the new collections in **Java 9**. They hope that by doing so users will more easily identify undesired order dependencies in their code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `HashMap` does explicitly define NO order of the elements you add. Like in a `HashSet` the elements are ordery by their hashcode and this is more or less random.

If you want to preserve the order in the Map in the order of insertion you can use a [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) instead. Or use a [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) if the elements should be sorted after the insertion.

Comment: I think by `Set` you explicitly mean `HashSet`, do you? Because other `Set` implementations may not order by hashcode.

Comment: I needed the `LinkedHashMap` so that they would stay in the order they were added.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of a HashMap is that you surrender control of the ordering, so that you can get performance gains on inserting and searching, and other benefits. To take back control of the ordering, look into using a [SortedMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
LinkedHashMap- preserve the insertion order.
TreeMap - Elements sorted after insertion.
```

HashMap doesn't maintain any order of inserted elements.

Answer (score 0):

HashMap doesn't add the values in the way you are adding it just adds the value randomly based on keys. For adding the values in the order you are adding use `LinkedHashMap` or if you want the Map in Alphabetically sorted order then use TreeMap. I hope this clears your doubt.